# Multiple overlapping indexes in CodeFirst using migrations

Tags: entity-framework

I have a problem getting `Add-Migration` create correct `migration.CreateIndex()` call. I have a POCO like this:

```
class MyPoco
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Index("IX_Test", 1)]
    int PartitionId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    int LocalId { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Test", 2)]
    int LocalId2 { get; set; }
}
```

From this `Add-Migration` generates `CreateIndex("dbo.MyPoco", "LocalId2", unique: true, name: "IX_Test");`. I expected something like `CreateIndex("dbo.MyPoco", new[] { "PartitionId", "LocalId2" }, unique: true, name: "IX_Test");`
The root cause seems to be that an EF model can only have one Index annotation per property (`customannotation:Index="{ Name: IX_Test, Order: 2, IsUnique: True }"` in generated migration EDMX). And since I don't use DB generated keys, EF create an Index intead, which seems to override my index.

Anyone know how to generate two overlapping indexes using EF Code First and have EF Migrations generate the correct output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a known bug in EF 6.1.1. Foreign key convention had a bug overwriting existing index annotations.

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2382

Solved by going to 6.1.2.